# Permissions required to access reports at https://reports.office.com/pbi with application

Tags: powerbi, office365api

Can somebody please tell me, what kind of permissions do I need to give to my application to be able to access the reports at https://reports.office.com/pbi ?

I already granted:

```
Microsoft Graph: Reports.Read.All
Office365 management APIs: ActivityReports.Read
Power BI service: Tenant.Read.All
```

When I try to read any report here, I see this response:

```
{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"We are sorry! You do not have permissions to see this data."}}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/power-bi-permissions

Comment: This page talks about delegated permissions. My app should run scheduled, without a signed-in user.

Comment: Same problem here! At the AAD App I can't find any API that matches "https://reports.office.com/pbi" to grant permissions. Do you have resolve this issue?

Comment: I have been working on this with MS premier support, but no solution so far. Workaround: Flow and HTTP with Azure AD action and using delegation. Too bad, this is a premium feature.

Comment: Finding that this reports API is not accesible on Azure App Permissions, I have chosen the hard way and I captured the browser authentication process with Fiddler and then I have reproduced all process requests in a powershell script. This way I can authenticate and download the reports.

Comment: official from support: this API is intended to be used internally, by Power BI, other use is not supported.